SSL_connect returns -1, SSL_get_error=1
I have two files, ca.crt and ca.key, generated using these commands:
openssl genrsa -out ca.key
openssl req -x509 -new -key ca.key -days 1825 -out ca.crt -subj "/CN=Root CA

Then I installed the ca.crt certificate in the "Trusted Root Certificate Authorities" on Windows.
And then I used this code to setup OpenSSL:
SSL_library_init();
SSLeay_add_ssl_algorithms();
SSL_load_error_strings();

SSL_CTX* ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv3_method());
SSL* ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
if (!ssl) {
    printf("ssl error\n");
    return -1;
}

SSL_set_fd(ssl, s);

if (SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, R"(mypath\to\ca.crt)", nullptr) <= 0) {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    printf("verify err\n");
}

if (!SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, R"(mypath\to\ca.key)", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM))
    printf("cert err 2\n");

int err = SSL_connect(ssl);
if (err <= 0) {
    printf("errno: %X\n", errno);
    printf("error creating ssl connection: %d\n", err);
    printf("%X\n", SSL_get_error(ssl, err));
    return -1;
}

Output:
errno: 0
error creating ssl connection: -1
1


Why are you using SSL v3.0? That is a dead and insecure version, nobody uses it anymore.  You should be using TLS instead of SSL, preferrably TLS v1.1 or v1.2 or even v1.3.

In any case, SSL_get_error() returning 1 is SSL_ERROR_SSL: "A non-recoverable, fatal error in the SSL library occurred, usually a protocol error. The OpenSSL error queue contains more information on the error." You need to call ERR_get_error() to get the error from the queue. And also, make sure to call ERR_clear_error() before any SSL function that is followed by SSL_get_error() so that you don't end up seeing old errors.

The code does not make any sense to me. Apart from using SSLv3_method it reads a private key with SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file without reading the matching certificate with SSL_CTX_use_certificate. Probably none of this should be used since the certificate in question is the trusted CA used for validate the server (that's why specified in SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations), not a client certificate used to   authenticate against the server. I'm not sure which examples this code is based on, but either the examples are broken or the code just too freely interprets examples and documentation.

Okay, i changed SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations to SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file, and SSL v3 to  TLSv1_2_method. Then i'm getting 5 error
